# Why $f(x)=e^x$ is a fixed point of $T$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-points

> Let $(C[0, 1], d_∞)$ be the metric space of continuous functions on
> $[0, 1]$ , where the distance function is defined by   $$d_∞(f,g)=
>  \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$$
>
> Consider the function $T:(C[0, 1], d_∞)\rightarrow (C[0, 1], d_∞)$
> defined by
>
> $$(Tf)(x):=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$

Why do we have $f(x)=e^x$ as a fixed point of $T$?

I am so confused because $T(e^x)=e^x-1$. But, $e^x \neq e^x-1$.

Comment: Where do you obtain the term -1?

Comment: I just plugged $f(x)=e^x$ into $T$. Which gives us, $(Tf)(x):=\int_{0}^{x}e^tdt=e^x-1$

Comment: @john Your question may be linked to my answer there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117556/proving-that-a-function-is-not-a-contraction/4117669#4117669
As the answer below shows, the constant in front of the exponential function must be zero, so there is indeed no fixed point. I have fixed my answer as well as it was not clear, and incorrect sometimes, thanks for your question.

Comment: @Nicolas Why do you say that there is no fixed point. Isn't the zero function a fixed point?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Indeed, I meant "no non-trivial fixed point". By the way, I need to clarify it in my answer, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not. The only fixed point is $0$. $Tf=f$ implies $f'(x)=f(x)$ so $f(x)=ce^{x}$ for some constant $c$. But $Tf(0)=0$ so we must have $c=0$.